# Unit test for method which calls void method in catch block and throws exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I have a project with Morphia ORM - Without transactions. And I have this method:

```
public void methodForTest() {
        try {
          methodCanThrowException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           methodWhiсhICanNotTest(template);
           throw new Exception("message of exception");
        }
    }

 private void methodWhiсhICanNotTest(String template){
  serviceWhichCanBeMockOne.clearAll(template);
  serviceWhichCanBeMockTwo.clearAll(template);
  serviceWhichCanBeMockThree.clearAll(template);

 }
```

Can I check that `methodWhiсhICanNotTest();`  was called? or how can I rewrite this code for easier testing?

Comment: if methodCanThrowException() is throwing exception, methodWhiсhICanNotTest(template) will get called. If not try throwing exception from methodCanThrowException()

Comment: @ kann I can throw an exception  in the first line of the method before  try

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE ANSWER FOR THE UPDATED QUESTION :D

If your `methodWhiсhICanNotTest` is a private method. Then you cannot verify it using Mockito in my previous answer. PowerMock is another solution for you. Read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method) and try it :-)

=======================

You can use Mockito to verify whether `methodWhiсhICanNotTest` is called.

```
Mockito.verify(abc.methodWhiсhICanNotTest())
```

Comment: doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...);

Comment: Too bad his code does **this**.methodWhichICanNotTest() ... so you would need the object under test to be a spy at least.

Comment: @StackFlowed there is no mocked object anywhere in the example code. There are just two methods under the same class under test ...

Comment: I need to verify 3 methods inside `methodWhiсhICanNotTest ` - `serviceWhichCanBeMockOne.clearAll(template);
  serviceWhichCanBeMockTwo.clearAll(template);
  serviceWhichCanBeMockThree.clearAll(template);` The problem in throwing of exception after.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov, an alternative solution is not to verify `methodWhiсhICanNotTest`, instead you can create three mock beans for `serviceWhichCanBeMockOne `,`serviceWhichCanBeMockTwo `,`serviceWhichCanBeMockThree ` and verify their method `clearAll`. Also, you can assert the expect exception throwing.